# Kotlin Enum class cannot have type parameters

Tags: kotlin, generics, enums

I have an enum as below

```
enum class AnimationSpecEnum(
    val descriptor: String,
    val animationSpec: AnimationSpec<Float>,
    val lowerBound: Float,
    val upperBound: Float,
    val duration: Int
) {
    TWEEN(
        "Tween 1000 0 LinearEasing",
        tween(1000, 0, LinearEasing),
        0f, 1f, 1000
    )
```

However, if I want to have a generic type of `AnumationSpec`

```
enum class AnimationSpecEnum<T>(
    val descriptor: String,
    val animationSpec: AnimationSpec<T>,
    val lowerBound: Float,
    val upperBound: Float,
    val duration: Int
) {
    TWEEN(
        "Tween 1000 0 LinearEasing",
        tween(1000, 0, LinearEasing),
        0f, 1f, 1000
    )
```

I was prompted with the error `Enum class cannot have type parameters`.

Is there a way for me to set the generic type in enum or any workaround while I can still use it as enum (instead of class)?

Comment: You may declare `animationSpec` field as `AnimationSpec<*>`.

Comment: Maybe a sealed class would work better than an enum for your case.